# PHP extensions installed through apt are not working

Tags: 16.04, php, php7

When I try to install PHP curl extension through apt, I get a message saying I already have the newest version installed.

However, it doesn't get loaded into PHP. What are possible reasons for this?

I'm using PHP 7 with nginx on Xenial.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this:

```
user@mybox:~$ lxc launch ubuntu:16.04 test
mybox:~$ lxc exec test /bin/bash
root@test:~# apt install php7.0-fpm php7.0-curl
root@test:~# php7.0 -i | grep -i curl
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
curl
cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => 7.47.0
```

make sure there is a symlink from `/etc/php/7.0/*/conf.d/20-curl.ini` to `/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/curl.ini`